# can't grep on 'java -version' output

Tags: java

I'm trying to grep on output from the commands:

```
java -version
java -XshowSettings
```

but it seems like they refuse to be redirected or piped.

I tried

```
java -version | grep whatever
java -version > jout.txt
```

but both just print the output to the screen.

What is going on?

Thanks,
Gilad.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to redirect to stdout before you can pipe like that. Those messages go to stderr by default, rather than stdout; that means that `grep` won't see the messages, and they'll just get printed to the console.

If this is Linux, try

```
java -version 2>&1 | grep whatever
```

and it should work. This will take all output to stderr from the `java` execution, and redirect it so that it goes to the same place as stdout; your `grep` invocation will then be able to see it.